# Django cannot find any valid urlpatterns

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to include a second urls.py in my main Django urls.py, and it's throwing this error whenever I try to do it:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'app.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Here's the main urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app_main.urls')),
]
```

Thanks! I don't think I have any circular imports, as I haven't really started creating the meat of the app yet. All help is appreciated. I'm curious as to why Django is doing this, as I'm pretty sure what I entered was a valid urlpattern (I checked it against one I knew to be valid).

Comment: What are the `urls` in `app_main`?

Comment: This exception is masking all errors on `python3.5` `django 2.2.1`. 
Downgrading it to 2.1 releases the debugger. Looking for a direct cause...

Comment: @fhjwbevbehjhb Did u solve it?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Carlton Gibson [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30500#comment:7), this bug is only present on Python 3.6.0 and earlier versions.
As Django currently supports 3.6.8 and later, you can either:

1. Update the python version
2. Reverse the [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/0636d4d2aa6e4469198fdf662225ad862e60c5e3) that's causing error-masking behavior, by removing try/except in `site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py`.